# Array filter and Array Display

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array and use JQuery to display it in 2 columns table.  But somehow it doesn't display into 2 columns as expected.

I also have 2 text fields to enter a from date and a to date in order to filter the table, but some how it doesn't work.

Please help.

Here is [live code](http://jsfiddle.net/abcid/WWscZ/)

HTML

```
<p>From:
  <input class="datepicker" id="dateFrom" type="text">To:
  <input class="datepicker" id="dateTo" type="text">
  <button class="buttApply">APPLY</button>
</p>

<div class="text"></div>
<table id="myTable" border="1" width="300" cellpadding="5">

</table>
```

JS

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker();


$('.buttApply').click(
  function() {
    var filtered = dateList.filter(function(item) {
      return item >= $('#dateFrom').val() && item <= $('#dateTo').val();
    });

    refreshTable(filtered);


  }
);

var dateList = [{
  name: "Mike Jenson",
  Date: "07/01/2014"
}, {
  name: "Liz Vinal",
  Date: "07/02/2014"
}, {
  name: "Robbin Jeson",
  Date: "07/03/2014"
}, {
  name: "Allen Greene",
  Date: "07/04/2014"
}, {
  name: "Dan Gray",
  Date: "07/05/2014"
}, {
  name: "Jann Johnson",
  Date: "07/06/2014"
}, {
  name: "Kelly Luther",
  Date: "07/07/2014"
}, {
  name: "Rock Mule",
  Date: "07/08/2014"
}, {
  name: "John Lenin",
  Date: "07/09/2014"
}, {
  name: "Micheal Jenn",
  Date: "07/10/2014"
}];

function refreshTable(list) {
  $("#myTable")..append("<tr><td>Name</td><td>Date</td></tr>");
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var tr = "<tr>";
    var td = "<td>" + list[i]["name"] + "</td>";
    var td = "<td>" + list[i]["Date"] + "</td></tr>";
    $('#myTable').append(tr + td + td);
  }
}

refreshTable(dateList);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer of your first problem

```
 But somehow it doesn't display into 2 columns as expected.
```

Try this in for loop

```
 var tr="<tr>";
 var td1 = "<td>" + list[i]["name"] + "</td>";
 var td2 = "<td>" + list[i]["Date"] + "</td></tr>";

 $('#myTable').append(tr+td1+td2);
```

You had both `tds` in same variable `td` so It was overwriting the first one.

And for your second problem do this, Because you are getting full object you have to compare with date.

```
 return item.Date >= $('#dateFrom').val() && item.Date <= $('#dateTo').val();
```

Comment: Thank you, Mritunjay for your help!

Comment: Thank you, Jay!  the update is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abcid/WWscZ/2/), but somehow it doesn't do filter!

Comment: @abcidd That's because you are appending to existing table put `$("#myTable").empty();` as first line of function `refreshTable`. I think this helped.

Comment: I just changed it to `$("#myTable").empty();` or `$("#myTable").html();` both work well! [Code update](http://jsfiddle.net/abcid/WWscZ/3/) The reason I want to get the append to the table is to get the column's headers `Name` and `Date` show up on the table.  I try to write these header's names in the HTML section, but somehow it doesn't print out!  How can I get these header's names show up on the table?

Comment: there is no headers in your table.

Comment: @abcidd change your `$("#myTable").html("");` to `$("#myTable").html(" <tr><td>Name</td><td>Date</td></tr>");` and remove from HTML

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57963/discussion-between-abcid-d-and-mritunjay).

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
var tr = "<tr>";
var tdName = "<td>" + list[i]["name"] + "</td>";
var tdDate = "<td>" + list[i]["Date"] + "</td></tr>";
$('#myTable').append(tr + tdName + tdDate);
```

Take a look and compare to your original code. `td` gets clobbered on the second `var td`.

Regarding the date filtering, you want this:

```
return item.Date >= $('#dateFrom').val() && item.Date <= $('#dateTo').val();
```

In your code, you are compare date values from user input to an object in your dateList. So the comparison looks something like this:

```
"07/04/2014" <= {name: "Mike Jenson", Date: "07/01/2014"} === ???
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/WWscZ/4/) Try this,

```
 var td = "<td>" + list[i]["name"] + "</td>";
 var td1 = "<td>" + list[i]["Date"] + "</td></tr>";
 $('#myTable').append(tr+td+td1);
```